# how to get each value from span and set all into variables using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, duplicates

I want check list of tags into div before add any words to not duplicate any word by jquery

```
$('.addTag').on('keyup',function(e){
var inputTag = e.keyCode || e.which;
var spanValues = document.getElementsByClassName('mini-tag');
var thisValue = $(this).val().slice(0,-1);
console.log(spanValues)
if(inputTag === 188){
  for(i=0;i<spanValues.length;i++){
    if(thisValue === spanValues[i]){
      $('.addTag').val('')
    }else{
      $('.tags').append("<span class='mini-tag'>" +  thisValue + 
       "<i class='fas fa-times fa-xs'></i>" + " "  + "</span>");
      $(this).val('');} 
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: please elaborate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: and also post the desired output

Comment: check list before add any tags in website to not duplicate words in tags

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML, in order that we can reproduce your problem? Please take a read of the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, also if you could post the relevant code as a "*[Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)*" that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the user releases a key you look at it and then if it's the terminating character (you have chosen the less than sign/left angle bracket) you get the whole string they have typed, minus the terminating character.

So far so good.

Where things go a bit awry is in your loop. You are stepping through each of the existing mini-tag span elements but you are testing the whole element against the value the user has typed in. You need to test against just the first text node otherwise you'll never get a match.

Also, what happens at the beginning, when there are no mini-tag elements? the length will be 0 so you'll never enter the loop - you'll never get started.

What we can do is remember whether we've got a match or not, break out of your loop when you've got a match, THEN append the mini-tag span if we haven't got a match.

Have a look at this snippet and the comments in the code.

BTW, one thing to be careful of is if your user types some nasty code into your input element you put it into the DOM and this could be dangerous. Since you are talking about tags you probably want to throw away any characters that aren't alphanumeric, but that depends on your use case.

```js
$('.addTag').on('keyup',function(e){
var inputTag = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (inputTag === 188) {
var spanValues = document.getElementsByClassName('mini-tag');
var thisValue = $(this).val().slice(0,-1);
console.log(spanValues)

//We just want to see if we have got a match
//We havent got one yet so let's remember that
let gotMatch = false;

//then go through testing the latest tag input against all those we already have to see if there is a match

  for(i=0;i<spanValues.length;i++){
    if(thisValue === spanValues[i].firstChild.nodeValue){
     gotMatch = true;
     break; //once we've got a match we know we don't want to carry on looking through the existing tags so get out of the for loop
    }
  }
    
    //now we have been through all the exising tags
    //we append a span element with the tag (and some fancy fontawesome)into the tags div
    
    if (!gotMatch) {
      $('.tags').append("<span class='mini-tag'>" +  thisValue + 
       "<i class='fas fa-times fa-xs'></i>" + " "  + "</span>"); 
       
    }
    $(this).val(''); //and whether we got a match or not we want to clear the input element so the user can type in another tag
}})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="addTag" type="text"/>
<div class="tags"></div>
```

Comment: thank you A Howorth , but when code run , show this error , want show error but i dont know how ???

Comment: I'm not seeing an error. Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: how show error here ??  -- if you have email to send error , send it

Comment: could you copy and paste it into a comment, or just type in the main part of it. Also, when do you get the error, when you type the terminating character to an input or any character or....

Comment: Thank you very much your code is prefect and working